How do I properly terminate a python multiprocessing process that runs a GStreamer pipeline
I am running a GStreamer pipeline in a separate Python multiprocessing process. The process captures frames from a camera to a multiprocessing Queue (full_frame_queue). I want to stop the process properly by first stopping the pipeline, and then waiting for the process to join. I am able to set the pipeline to NULL, and the queue is empty, but still the process does not join. Here is how I start the pipeline process:
    def start(self):
        Gst.init(None)
        self.capture_process = Process(target=self.capture_frame)
        self.capture_process.start()

Here is the capture_frame method that gets run in the process:
    def capture_frame(self):
        pipeline = self.__start_gstreamer_pipeline()
        full_sink = pipeline.get_by_name("full_sink")
        if not pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING):
            raise RuntimeError("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.")
        try:
            while self.running.is_set():
                full_sample = full_sink.emit("pull-sample")
                if full_sample:
                    self.process_frame(full_sample)
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
        finally:
            Gst.Element.send_event(pipeline, Gst.Event.new_eos())
            print("EoS sent")
            pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            print("Switched to NULL state")

Here is where I initiate stopping the process by clearing the running event, causing capture_frame to enter the finally block:
    def stop(self):
        if self.capture_process:
            self.running.clear()
            while not not self.full_frame_queue.empty():
                self.full_frame_queue.get()
            self.capture_process.join(timeout=10)
            print("Capture process joined")

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Posting separate, granular methods of a class, without the imports or calling code that would allow one to replicate the problem, does not help. we can't even know if the three methods are in the same class, and, more importantly in this case, what is self.running and where it is created (likely in the class __init__. )
